# How is this Variational Quantum Singular Value Decomposition paper efficient in any way?

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-algorithms, vqe, matrix-representation

Link to paper [here](https://quantum-journal.org/papers/q-2021-06-29-483/pdf/).
This algorithm seems neat but the unitary decomposition of the matrix M generally takes an exponential number of Pauli basis elements in the number of qubits $N$, therefore an exponential number of Hadamard tests. Likewise, to reconstruct $U$ and $V$ we need to measure all column vectors which is really inefficient. So how does this paper offer a speedup of any kind, wouldn't classical SVD just be orders of magnitude faster?